# Why can't I get my expected result from a function decorated by async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have some code like below

```
'use strict';
function greeting() {
  console.log('Hello ' + getName());
}

async function getName() {
  return 'Fred';
}

greeting();
```

I was expecting the output would be `Hello Fred`, however it returns me `Hello[object Promise]`. I know it isn't necessary to decorate `getName()` by `async`, I'm just describing a similar situation I run into.

Comment: `async` - is asynchronous - why would you expect a synchronous result? `async/await` is "sugar" for Promises, so what you are getting is a Promise ... use .then - and, also, why do you want to make such synchronous code return the result asynchronously?

Comment: The pattern is generally called "async/await". You have no `await` in your code.

Comment: @JaromandaX For learning/experimentation purposes, most likely

Comment: as @JaromandaX already suggested, async functions return a promise. You can do something like:
function greeting() {
  getName().then(val=>{console.log('Hello ' + val)});
}

async function getName() {
  return 'Fred';
}

greeting();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async functions must be called using the `await` keyword. `async` functions always return a promise with the returned value, and `await` "pulls" the value out of a promise. `await` can only be used inside of async functions.

```
async function getName() {
  return 'Fred'
}

async function greeting() {
  console.log('Hello ' + await getName())
}

greeting()
  // while this isn't *required*, it's good practice to always handle promise errors
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function